# Unable to get tezos-node to connect to P2P network

Tags: node, p2p

My tezos-node is unable to connect to the gossip network and synchronize with peers.
I think some restrictions are imposed in my organization's network.

I ran nmap on my organization' gateway IP Address to check which ports are open. Only port 80 is open. The rest of the ports are filtered.

What could be the reason for this ? Due to the ports being blocked or some other reason?

I have attached the screenshot of the verbose generated while running tezos-node. Kindly suggest what I should do to resolve this issue.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Don't do personal business at work.

Comment: It's actually a part of my work.

Comment: Awesome! It's rare for crypto to be part of people's "work" so I sniped that comment. No offense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Only port 80 is open. The rest of the ports are filtered.

Very typical in most corp/org settings. They don't want you running services/servers on their network.

If your organization's firewall/NAT blocks outbound 9732 then you won't ever be able to connect to other nodes. Additionally, for other nodes to contact *you*, the firewall/NAT would have to allow incoming 9732 AND route that traffic to your specific IP. (I seriously doubt any network/IT person would ever accept this request when you explain what it is for).

You could try doing a VPN from your node which would bypass your corp FW/NAT for outbound connections, but they might be blocking standard VPN ports as well.

Comment: Thank you for your reply :)